# Reinstall Ubuntu 14.04 from the terminal window

Tags: 14.04, command-line

Any Code to put in the terminal that will bring back the settings to original ???

Comment: Which settings do you wish to reset? What caused the issue you are having? What hardware are you using? etc

Answer (score 5):

The following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

may solve your problems.

Answer (score 2):

To reset your Ubuntu desktop to it's original state, open a terminal and apply the following commands:

```
sudo gconftool --shutdown
sudo killall -r -I gconf
sudo killall -r -I dconf
sudo rm -rf .compiz* .gconf* .config/dconf/ .config/compiz*
```

Reboot your PC, or use the command `sudo shutdown -r now`